# Rails form_for and fields_for not rendering values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Using `form_for` in Rails I cannot get it to render the values:

```
form_for(@foo) do |f|
  f.fields_for(:bar) do |b|
    b.text_field :baz
  end
end
```

It renders the input fine but the value of the input is always blank.

However, if I don't use the symbols it then works, but the names of the inputs are causing a problem when I have 2 relations from the same table, ie, two of the inputs will have the same name.

```
form_for(@foo) do |f|
  f.fields_for(@foo.bar || Bar.new) do |b|
    b.text_field :baz
  end
end
```

Comment: Have you added "accepts_nested_attributes_for :bar" in your foo model?

Comment: I did but then the entire input didn't render

Comment: Can you show your model, with the real attribute names if possible?

Comment: I think it isn't rendering this field because it has no value. There are other fields that are rendered fine and they have values.